# How to Query fragments in a subtree of a top level query in a GraphQL server

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Let's say a graphql server exists with the following schema:

```
query
 -currentUser
 --data1
 --data2
 ...
```

Assume on your client, on page 1 of your app, you want data1 and page 2, you want data2. If I update data2 and want to refetch the query, do I need to query from the top level, resolving currentUser in order to get the updated data2? Is the only way around this by creating a root-level query for data2? E.g.:

```
query
-currentUser
--data1
--data2
-data2 (query on root of tree to avoid repeated currentUser calls)
```

Edit: I'm interested in how to do this using Apollo-client for React

Answer (score 0):

The Relay [top-level node query](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/graphql-server-specification.html#object-identification) gives a standard way to do this.  If most objects implement its `Node` interface, then you can use the top-level `node(id: ID!)` query to retrieve a specific object.

```
query GetFirstDatum {
  currentUser {
    id
    data1
  }
}
query GetSecondDatum($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on User {
      data2
    }
  }
}
```

This requires providing the `Node` interface in your IDL, having your objects implement it, and providing an implementation of the top-level `node` query that can return an object given its ID.  Most server libraries have some level of support for this.

Comment: Also if you already have a named fragment (which includes a type match) you can just drop that in where I have the `... on User` block.  I’m not sure whether the question uses “fragment” as a technical term.